# How does spark deal with unequal node performance?

Tags: apache-spark

Lets say I have map function that is run over 1000 data inputs and each takes between 1 min for a fast core and 4 min for a slow core. Lets say I have 100 cores, 50 are fast, 50 are slow.

If spark assigns each core 10 task each, the fast cores will finish their allocated tasks much earlier than the slow cores. Does the master know this and redistribute the tasks to the now free fast cores? In other words, are the fast cores being used optimally for the best overall execution time? Or do the fast cores finish, and sit idle while the master is waiting for the slow cores to finish?

I'm running spark 1.6 if that helps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tasks are scheduled one at a time.  If one core takes 10 seconds for a task and another core takes 30 seconds for a task, the first core will do three tasks in the time the second core does one task.  The scheduler does not put ten tasks per core and wait for them to do all ten: it assigns a single task per core, and then when the core finishes it assigns another task.  According to queuing theory this will be much faster than having a separate queue of tasks per node -- this is also well known, so no good scheduler will have separate queues per core unless there are significant extenuating circumstances.

Comment: Thanks - that's what I hoped was happening :-)